# How to migrate Sybase Application to Web?

Tags: sybase

I have a client asking me to migrate his Sybase application to web. I have worked on PHP/MySQL, C#/Ms-Sql but never worked with Sybase platform!

Please suggest me some ways i can go through this. How would we migrate existing Sybase desktop application to web application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll find that Sybase is very similar to SQL Server, they share the same TSQL language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSQL

Comment: thanks. i am getting it slowly. but what about the Sybase web application development environment and hosting process?? Are there Sybase supporting hosting providers available? i really want to give time to this project. Can you share me some thoughts on Sybase web application deployment?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have a sybase database online.
With a simple search on google you may choose the [site](https://www.google.com/search?q=sybase%20database%20hosting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3apt-PT%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) that you need :)

Now, to pass all the database info (tables and content, sps, etc.) for the remote database you'll need to do two things:

1. Use [ddlgen](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility204.htm) batch to extract all the tables/views and stored procedures code.
2. Use [bcp](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/util/@Generic__BookTextView/10086;pt=9512) to extract all the info from the tables.